# Can I create another bank account in a different branch in China?

Tags: banking, china

I already have a few Chinese bank accounts (ICBC, Construction Bank, and China Merchants Bank). But all of them were opened in Shanghai, and I want to create a new account in different cities.

So can I create another account in Hangzhou or Shenzhen, in the same bank but a different branch?

---

#### UPDATE

I tried to open it in ICBC in another city but got declined.

Comment: Why do you want to have two accounts with the same bank, but in different branches?  Why can't you go into a branch of ICBC in Shenzhen, and do whatever you want to do with your account in Shanghai?

Answer (score 0):

As a tourist, it will be harder to open a new bank account with the bigger banks, like ICBC or BoC.

If you're planning to spend some time in China, and can/are willing to register for a language class, a student visa will be the easiest way to open a new bank account. Say you want to stay for a while in Shenzhen. You register for a semester in ShenDa, get your student ID card, and head over to the banks they have on campus, BoC for sure, and Communications I think. You'll have a shiny new bank account in no time.

Failing that, it is going to be harder. Go for the smaller banks, in areas with a lot of foreigners. They might be less strict.

Comment: Thanks but this is not correct. You can open a bank account as a tourist [as suggested by this answer over Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73555/can-i-apply-for-a-unionpay-card-while-traveling-in-china#73567). I created my own as a tourist at three banks, though BoC didn't allow me. Also my question is about whether I can create another bank account at a different branch in China, not the first time opening.